# Installing WindowBuilder on Jboss?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ide, windowsbuilder

Is there a way to install the WindowsBuilder plugin in the Jboss IDE? I have previously installed it in eclipse but I cannot in jboss. or there is another plugin that they recommend to me to make windows easier

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Developer Studio 11.3.0 is based on eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen).
Open JBoss Developer Studio go to Help > Install new software. Press Add for the new repositories. Use "WindowBuilder" for name and for address use this link `http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/`
Accept license terms ...Install ... restart ... and enjoy!